# Add part of an integer to bytearray

Tags: python, integer, arrays

```
i = 34
ba = bytearray()
```

Now I want to add the two least significant bytes of `i` to `ba`. How can I do that?

Comment: Your question lacks essential information: what byte representation for the number do you want to use? 2-complement? 1-complement? sign+magnitude? mantissa+exponent? or an other of the *unlimited* number you can define?

Comment: @Bakuriu, I want to copy the two lowest bytes from the integer as is. In other words, I want to 'slice' the integer into two parts of two bytes each and copy the first one into the bytearray.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`int.to_bytes`](http://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#int.to_bytes) method to convert the integer to its binary representation as bytes. Passing `signed=True` you get the 2-complement representation:

```
In [1]: i = 34

In [2]: i.to_bytes(length=2, byteorder='big')
Out[2]: b'\x00"'
```

You can then `extend` the `bytearray` with the result:

```
In [3]: ba = bytearray()

In [4]: ba.extend(i.to_bytes(length=2, byteorder='big'))

In [5]: ba
Out[5]: bytearray(b'\x00"')
```

Changing `'big'` to `'little'` you effectively reverse the order in which bytes are added to the bytearray.

If you are using python2 you can use a function such as:

```
def to_bytes(num, length, order):
    res = bytearray(length)
    for i in range(length):
        res[i] = num & 0xff
        num >>= 8
    if num:
        raise OverflowError("Number {} doesn't fit into {} bytes.".format(num, length))
    if order == 'little':
        res.reverse()
    return res
```